# Cyrillic does not work in Itext 7

Tags: java, itext

```
PdfFont fontrus = PdfFontFactory.createFont(FONTrus, "CP1251", true); 
String a = "\u041e\u0442\u043a\u0443\u0434\u0430 \u0442\u044b?"; 
String b = "Привет мир"; 

Text text = new Text(a);


Text text1 = new Text(b);   
text.setFont(fontrus);
text1.setFont(fontrus); 
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph()
                        .add(text).setFontSize(15);
Paragraph paragraph1 = new Paragraph()
                        .add(b).setFontSize(15);
```

**work**-

> String a = "\u041e\u0442\u043a\u0443\u0434\u0430 \u0442\u044b?";

**don't work -**

> String b = "Привет мир";

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKFPC.png)

Everything works in itext 5, but does not work in itext7

Comment: `PdfFontFactory.createFont(FONTrus, "CP1251", true);` Shouldn't this be just FONT instead of FONTrus? `PdfFontFactory.createFont(FONT, "CP1251", true);`

Comment: public static final String FONTrus = "./src/main/resources/OlgaCTT.ttf";

Comment: Isn't it a problem with the source file encoding?

Comment: in itext 5 work.

Comment: String b probably has the wrong encoding, don't use text like that, but use the unicode representation.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is definitely NOT in the way you define the string variables. It is in the fact that, although you setFont() for text B, you don't use it when creating a new Paragraph. So:

```java
Paragraph paragraph1 = new Paragraph()
                        .add(b).setFontSize(15);
```

should be:

```java
Paragraph paragraph1 = new Paragraph()
                        .add(text1).setFontSize(15);
```

Mind the `.add(text1)` vs `add(b)`.
With this fix only, both lines are output in the PDF.